# How to prevent a vertically-centered div from disappearing off of small screens

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS that I use to vertically center a DIV on a page (and horizontally center it as well).  If the height of the browser window is less than 600px, I would like the window to be able to scroll to show the entire DIV.  However, the DIV just centers itself on the page and anything beyond the height of the browser is hidden--no scroll bars.  Is there any way to allow the user to scroll to these now hidden regions?

```
#container{
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-300px;
    top:50%;
    margin-left:-400px;
    left:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `@media` query for `max-width` and `max-height`

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    #container {
        left: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 600px) {
    #container {
        top: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ULML/)

Answer (score 0):

you could also try adding

```
overflow:scroll;
```

The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

Answer (score 0):

check this one

```
#container{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
width: 30em;
height: 18em;
margin-top: -9em;
margin-left: -15em;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Comment: you need to change the height, width, margin as of your requirement

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
  #container
    {
    width:800px;
    height:600px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }
```

Comment: I've already set margin-left to a specific amount to center the DIV horizontally.  How would this effect the vertical visibility of the DIV?

Answer (score -1):

You are using `position: absolute;` so there's no way this can be achieved unless and until you make a `div` with `min-width` and `margin` set to `auto`

```
<div>vertically centered div</div>
<div>min-width div</div>

div:nth-of-type(2) {
   min-width: 1000px; /*Change accordingly*/
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but it seemed to have no effect.  Could you post a jsfiddle script or explain how the second DIV is effects the visibility of the vertically centered DIV?